# Jquery UI Slider, reveal an image as you drag across

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

I have a Jquery UI slider, and as I drag the slider across I want to reveal a background image.  The challenge of this is I don't know the width of the UI slider (since it is responsive and changes based on screen width).  So the image will have to figure out how long the slider is, and fit that.  Furthermore, only the parts of the image that have been dragged over should be revealed, so not the entire image.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this effect? Thank you!

Comment: You mean something like that: http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty ?

Comment: post your code in your question please.